# Bundles not rendering correctly in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a new MVC application and foolishly didn't use an app template so I've had to setup all the nuget packages by hand. I think I still must be missing something because my bundles are rendering incorrectly.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

renders as

```
<link href="/Content/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

even though i've got `<compilation debug="true" />` in web.config and `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` in my bundle configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the instant I ask the question I work out the answer.

The global.asax.cs didn't call the `RegisterBundle` method.

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```